# I am trying to create a corpus using pdf documents

Tags: pdf, import, document, corpus, pdftools

When I am writing the code, I am getting the following error:

> PDF error: Unknown Metadata type: 'XMP'
> PDF error: Unknown Metadata type: 'XMP'

```
corp <- Corpus(URISource(files),
               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```

I have saved all the pdf documents in the working directory, I have created the vector using the following code :

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
```

and I am able to see the length of each pdf file using the following piece of codes:

```
my_corpus <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
length(my_corpus)
lapply(my_corpus, length)
```

How can I solve this?